# ValidationRules

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In a wpf view, i have 3 textboxes which implement a custom validation rules like this :

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Height="30"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Grid.Column="1"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         Width="150"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Model.Age"
             Mode="TwoWay"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
             ValidatesOnExceptions="True"
             ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <validation:DataTypeValidationRules DataTypeRule="Required"
                                            ErrorMessage="Required field" />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

My problem is : If i change the text directly in textbox, the validation work and i can see my template if the textbox has no value, but if i do nothing in the view and click on my save button, which has a command binding to my ViewModel, the validation is not working, because i think there is no OnPropertyChange event who was raised, so i need to check again if the value is not empty in my viewmodel, and i don't want to do this like that.

Note : I'm using the MVVM pattern

Sorry for my English and many thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of that this problem can happen is when the text is being set from the viewmodel and not from the UI, in which case this is really a problem, since the validation rule won't be reevaluated.

To solve this, you can implement the [`IDataErrorInfo` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx), or better yet, the [`INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you're targeting .NET 4.5). Not only will this solve your problem, but it's also the MVVM way of performing validations (you are currently defining validation logic in XAML, which isn't good). Once you do this, you can remove the binding rules from your XAML as well.

Implementation example:

```
public class ViewModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (propertyName == "Age")
            {
                if (Age < 18)
                {
                    return "Age must be at least 18.";
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My Model implements IDataErrorInfo, i use this to validate the business rules, and for input validation i want to use it in xaml, by this way, i should move all input validation in the model too, for ex: check if a field is still empty. thanks